# Least angle regression keeps the correlations monotonically decreasing and tied?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, correlation, self-study

I'm trying to solve a problem for least angle regression (LAR). This is a problem **3.23** on page **97** of [Hastie et al., Elements of Statistical Learning, 2nd. ed. (5th printing)](http://www.stanford.edu/~hastie/local.ftp/Springer/ESLII_print5.pdf#page=115).

Consider a regression problem with all variables and response having mean zero and standard deviation one.  Suppose also that each variable has identical absolute correlation with the response:

$
\frac{1}{N} | \left \langle \bf{x}_j, \bf{y} \right \rangle | = \lambda, j = 1, ..., p
$

Let $\hat{\beta}$ be the least squares coefficient of $\mathbf{y}$ on $\mathbf{X}$ and let $\mathbf{u}(\alpha)=\alpha \bf{X} \hat{\beta}$ for $\alpha\in[0,1]$.

I am asked to show that
$$
\frac{1}{N} | \left \langle \bf{x}_j, \bf{y}-u(\alpha) \right \rangle | = (1 - \alpha) \lambda, j = 1, ..., p
$$
and I am having problems with that. Note that this can basically  says that the correlations of each $x_j$ with the residuals remain equal
in magnitude as we progress toward $u$.

I also do not know how to show that  the correlations are equal to:

$\lambda(\alpha) = \frac{(1-\alpha)}{\sqrt{(1-\alpha)^2 + \frac{\alpha (2-\alpha)}{N} \cdot RSS}} \cdot \lambda$

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: @Belmont, what is $u(\alpha)$? Could you provide more context about your problem? Link to article with standard properties of LAR for example would help a lot.

Comment: @Belmont, This looks like a problem from Hastie, et al., *Elements of Statistical Learning*, 2nd. ed. Is this homework? If so, you might add that tag.

Comment: @Belmont, now that @cardinal gave a complete answer, can you specify what LAR really is, for future reference? Judging from the answer this is standard manipulation of products of least squares regressions given some initial constraints. There should not be a special name for it without serious reason.

Comment: @mpiktas, LAR stands for *least angle regression* as coined by Efron et al. In their 2004 paper. It is closely related to both forward-stagewise regression and the lasso. Indeed it allows the *full* regularization path of each of these to be calculated with the same computational complexity of a single least-squares fit. (Note that both methods reduce to least-squares when the shrinkage goes to zero.) LAR was discovered and developed after the similarities in the regularization paths of the coefficients in forward-stagewise and the lasso were noted.

Comment: @cardinal, but if we regularize $\beta$ why $u(\alpha)=\alpha X\hat{\beta}$, with $\hat{\beta}$ LS estimate?

Comment: @mpiktas, it's a stagewise algorithm, so each time a variable enters or leaves the model on the regularization path, the size (i.e., cardinality/dimension) of $\beta$ grows or shrinks respectively and a "new" LS estimate is used based on the currently "active" variables. In the case of the lasso, which is a convex optimization problem, the procedure is is essentially exploiting special structure in the KKT conditions to obtain a *very* efficient solution. There are also generalizations to, e.g., logistic regression based on IRLS and Heine-Borel (to prove convergence in finite no. of steps.)

Comment: @cardinal, thanks for trying to explain. I understand the idea, but some of the details are still not clear, I see though that I can figure them out myself using the references you gave.

Comment: @mpiktas, unfortunately I'm not aware of a good overview treatment of the algorithm. The Hastie et al. text has a handful of pages on it, but as with most of the methods discussed in the book, many significant details are missing. The original Efron et al. paper is at least 45 pages long, if I recall, which requires some determination to get through. Perhaps there is a gap in the literature to be filled.

Comment: @cardinal, ok I got the Efron paper, will spend few evenings reading it instead of answering questions here :)

Comment: @Belmont -1, as I recently bought the book of Hastie, I can confirm, that this is an exercise from it. So I am giving you a big -1, since you do not even manage to give all the definitions, I am not even talking about giving the reference.

Comment: @mpiktas Apologies...wasn't trying to confuse; clearly didn't ask the question effectively.  Thanks for the help in clarifying it!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This is problem **3.23** on page **97** of [Hastie et al., *Elements of Statistical Learning*, 2nd. ed. (5th printing)](http://www.stanford.edu/~hastie/local.ftp/Springer/ESLII_print5.pdf#page=115).

The key to this problem is a good understanding of ordinary least squares (i.e., linear regression), particularly the orthogonality of the fitted values and the residuals.

**Orthogonality lemma**: Let $X$ be the $n \times p$ design matrix, $y$ the response vector and $\beta$ the (true) parameters. Assuming $X$ is full-rank (which we will throughout), the OLS estimates of $\beta$ are $\hat{\beta} = (X^T X)^{-1} X^T y$. The fitted values are $\hat{y} = X (X^T X)^{-1} X^T y$. Then $\langle \hat{y}, y-\hat{y} \rangle = \hat{y}^T (y - \hat{y}) = 0$. That is, the fitted values are *orthogonal* to the residuals. This follows since $X^T (y - \hat{y}) = X^T y - X^T X (X^T X)^{-1} X^T y = X^T y - X^T y = 0$.

Now, let $x_j$ be a column vector such that $x_j$ is the $j$th column of $X$. The assumed conditions are:

- $\frac{1}{N} \langle x_j, x_j \rangle = 1$ for each $j$, $\frac{1}{N} \langle y, y \rangle = 1$,
- $\frac{1}{N} \langle x_j, 1_p \rangle = \frac{1}{N} \langle y, 1_p \rangle = 0$ where $1_p$ denotes a vector of ones of length $p$, and
- $\frac{1}{N} | \langle x_j, y \rangle | = \lambda$ for all $j$.

Note that **in particular**, the last statement of the **orthogonality lemma** is identical to $\langle x_j, y - \hat{y} \rangle = 0$ for all $j$.

---

**The correlations are tied**

Now, $u(\alpha) = \alpha X \hat{\beta} = \alpha \hat{y}$. So,
$$
\langle x_j, y - u(a) \rangle = \langle x_j, (1-\alpha) y + \alpha y - \alpha \hat{y} \rangle = (1-\alpha) \langle x_j, y \rangle + \alpha \langle x_j, y - \hat{y} \rangle ,
$$
and the second term on the right-hand side is zero by the **orthogonality lemma**, so
$$
\frac{1}{N} | \langle x_j, y - u(\alpha) \rangle | = (1-\alpha) \lambda ,
$$
as desired. The absolute value of the correlations are just
$$
\hat{\rho}_j(\alpha) = \frac{\frac{1}{N} | \langle x_j, y - u(\alpha) \rangle |}{\sqrt{\frac{1}{N} \langle x_j, x_j \rangle }\sqrt{\frac{1}{N} \langle y - u(\alpha), y - u(\alpha) \rangle }} = \frac{(1-\alpha)\lambda}{\sqrt{\frac{1}{N} \langle y - u(\alpha), y - u(\alpha) \rangle }} 
$$

**Note**: The right-hand side above is independent of $j$ and the numerator is just the same as the covariance since we've assumed that all the $x_j$'s and $y$ are centered (so, in particular, no subtraction of the mean is necessary).

**What's the point?** As $\alpha$ increases the response vector is modified so that it inches its way toward that of the (*restricted!*) least-squares solution obtained from incorporating only the first $p$ parameters in the model. This simultaneously modifies the estimated parameters since they are simple inner products of the predictors with the (modified) response vector. The modification takes a special form though. It keeps the (magnitude of) the correlations between the predictors and the modified response the same throughout the process (even though the *value* of the correlation is changing). Think about what this is doing geometrically and you'll understand the name of the procedure!

---

**Explicit form of the (absolute) correlation**

Let's focus on the term in the denominator, since the numerator is already in the required form. We have
$$
\langle y - u(\alpha), y - u(\alpha) \rangle = \langle (1-\alpha) y + \alpha y - u(\alpha), (1-\alpha) y + \alpha y - u(\alpha) \rangle .
$$

Substituting in $u(\alpha) = \alpha \hat{y}$ and using the linearity of the inner product, we get

$$
\langle y - u(\alpha), y - u(\alpha) \rangle = (1-\alpha)^2 \langle y, y \rangle + 2\alpha(1-\alpha) \langle y, y - \hat{y} \rangle + \alpha^2 \langle y-\hat{y}, y-\hat{y} \rangle .
$$

Observe that

- $\langle y, y \rangle = N$ by assumption,
- $\langle y, y - \hat{y} \rangle = \langle y - \hat{y}, y - \hat{y} \rangle + \langle \hat{y}, y - \hat{y} \rangle = \langle y - \hat{y}, y - \hat{y}\rangle$, by applying the **orthogonality lemma** (yet again) to the second term in the middle; and,
- $\langle y - \hat{y}, y - \hat{y} \rangle = \mathrm{RSS}$ by definition.

Putting this all together, you'll notice that we get

$$
\hat{\rho}_j(\alpha) = \frac{(1-\alpha) \lambda}{\sqrt{ (1-\alpha)^2 + \frac{\alpha(2-\alpha)}{N} \mathrm{RSS}}} =  \frac{(1-\alpha) \lambda}{\sqrt{ (1-\alpha)^2 (1 - \frac{\mathrm{RSS}}{N}) + \frac{1}{N} \mathrm{RSS}}}
$$

To wrap things up, $1 - \frac{\mathrm{RSS}}{N} = \frac{1}{N} (\langle y, y, \rangle - \langle y - \hat{y}, y - \hat{y} \rangle ) \geq 0$ and so it's clear that $\hat{\rho}_j(\alpha)$ is monotonically decreasing in $\alpha$ and $\hat{\rho}_j(\alpha) \downarrow 0$ as $\alpha \uparrow 1$.

---

**Epilogue**: Concentrate on the ideas here. There is really only one. The **orthogonality lemma** does almost all the work for us. The rest is just algebra, notation, and the ability to put these last two to work.

Comment: @cardinal, +1. The answer is magnitudes better than the question.

Comment: @cardinal, you might want to change the link to amazon or some other site. I think that linking to the full book might raise some copyright issues.

Comment: @mpiktas, nope. No copyright issues. That is the official website for the book. The authors obtained permission from Springer to make the PDF freely available online. (See the note to this effect on the site.) I think they got the idea from Stephen Boyd and his *Convex Optimization* text. Hopefully such a trend will pick up steam over the next few years. Enjoy!

Comment: @cardinal, ooh massive thanks! That is mighty generous from the authors.

Comment: @mpiktas, it's by far the most popular book in the Springer Series in Statistics. It looks good on an iPad. Which reminds me---I should download Boyd's text onto it as well. Cheers.

Comment: @cardinal, it looks good on Kindle too, also Boyd's too :)

Comment: @mpiktas, the Kindle must have gotten better at displaying books with math. When it first came out, I heard that it was useless for such a purpose.

Comment: @cardinal, the new kindle displays pdf files just fine. There are some corner cases, but if pdf is nice, it looks pretty good.

Comment: Only the last assumption was given in the text. Why the first 3 assumptions posted by cardinal are true? 1/N⟨xj,xj⟩=1 for each j, 1/N⟨y,y⟩=1,
1/N⟨xj,1p⟩=1/N⟨y,1p⟩=0 where 1p denotes a vector of ones of length p.

Comment: *Consider a regression problem with all variables and response having mean zero and standard deviation one.* (I simply restated this using mathematical notation, hopefully to make the following development clearer.)

Comment: Sorry @cardinal, if I'm a bit slow. You meant E[<x_j, x_j>] = N * E[x_{i, j} * x_{i, j}].
Var[x_{i, j}] = 1. E[x_{i, j}] = 0. (E[x_{i, j}])^2 = 0. This implies E[(x_{i, j})^2] = 1.
Hence E[1/N [<x_j, x_j>]] = 1.

Comment: The reference the authors are making to *mean zero* and *standard deviation one* simply refer to the sample means and standard deviations of the predictors and response. In other words, the predictors have been centered and scaled and the response has also been centered.