# What optimization problem does least angle regression try to solve?

Tags: regression, optimization

In Hastie et al's Elements of Statistical Learning, it says

> Least angle regression (LAR) ... can be viewed as a kind of “democratic” version of forward stepwise regression (Section 3.3.2). As we will see, LAR is intimately connected
>   with the lasso, and in fact provides an extremely eﬃcient algorithm for
>   computing the entire lasso path as in Figure 3.10.

Forward stepwise regression tries to solve the following optimization problem for selection of best subset of features:
$$
\min_x \|Ax-b\|_2
$$
s.t.
$$
\|x\|_0 \leq M.
$$

LASSO tries to solve the following optimization problem
$$
\min_x \|Ax-b\|_2
$$
s.t.
$$
\|x\|_1 \leq \epsilon.
$$

I was wondering what optimization problem does least angle regression try to solve?

Thanks!

Comment: i think it's important to point out that forward stepwise does indeed *try* to solve the first problem, but lasso *does* solve the second problem.

Answer (score 1):

If I don't miss anything, LAR tries to solve the same optimization problem with LASSO in a way that the solutions for all possible equivalent $\epsilon$s are given (i.e., the so-called LASSO path)

Comment: Thanks! (1) In Hastie's ESL, algorithm 3.2 for LAR is modified in algorithm 3.2a to provide solutions to the optimization problem of LASSO. So I think LAR solves a different optimization problem? (2) in algorithm 3.2 and 3.2a, I don't see they solve for every values of $\epsilon$?

Comment: (3) what does equivalent $\epsilon$'s mean? If some $\epsilon$'s are equivalent, are their solutions the same?

Comment: Equivalent $\epsilon$s, by definition, lead to the same minimizer for LASSO problem.

Comment: Thanks! I was wondering why LAR solves for the solutions for all values of $\epsilon$?