# Geometrical interpretation of correlation of a variable and the residual

Tags: correlation, residuals, intuition, geometry

I came across [this blog post](http://blog.echen.me/2011/04/21/a-mathematical-introduction-to-least-angle-regression/) about least angle regression, and at a point he says:

> - Find the variable $x_1$ most correlated with the residual. (Note that the variable most correlated with the residual is equivalently the one that makes the least angle with the residual, whence the name.)
> - Move in the direction of this variable until some other variable $x_2$ is just as correlated.

But I couldn't visualize it. By "residual" he is referring to the vectors minus the average of the vectors, am I right? What could be a geometrical interpretation of "variable correlation with the residual"? What would be a, let's say, 2D example of this interpretation?

Comment: http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/1448

Comment: see also "13 ways to look at the correlation coefficient" by Rodgers and Nicewander: http://data.psych.udel.edu/laurenceau/PSY861Psychological%20Statistics%20II%20Spring%202010/READINGS/rodgers-nicewander-1988-r-13-ways.pdf

Comment: The original LARS paper has several illustrative figures of the procedure. Have you also looked there? The linked blog post has an adapted version of one of them.

Comment: No pictures, but related: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/6795/least-angle-regression-keeps-the-correlations-monotonically-decreasing-and-tied/6933#6933

Comment: @shabby: this article is incredible! I really love this kind of reasoning, multiple point of views in the same concept... Fantastic!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When two variables are highly correlated it means that when you do a scatter plot of the observed pairs they will fall close to a straight line.  It is the same here except that one of the variables is a residual.  In two dimensions looking at vectors suppose you move from the point (Xmean, Ymean) to a point (Xmean + D, Ymean + E)  That vector will have slope E/D.  Now if the residual vector at (Xmean + D, Ymean + E) has a change in X and Y similar to the change for the variable X1 being considered it will be highly correlated with X1.