# Constant signs of correlation in the active set in least angle regression

Tags: correlation, proof, lars

I am trying to comprehend the proof of the Least Angle Regression algorithm and I am stuck at certain points. I would appreciate any help that I can get.

Let me set the stage:
I am following the paper in the following [link](http://www.stanford.edu/~hastie/Papers/LARS/LeastAngle_2002.pdf)

On Page 8, in the paper, they make the following claim (restated in my own words).

> The sign of the correlation of every predictor in the active set stays
>   a constant.

Though I intuitively understand it I am trying to formally prove this claim.

I have some ideas, but none give me conclusive proof. For example if I end up proving that the step taken in the equi-angular direction is less than the least squares step then I am done. But I am not able to prove that either.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Related: http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/6795/2970

Comment: I removed your signature, as the site adds it automatically